# Python- Deleting a sheet in excel without it prompting you

Tags: python, excel

How do you delete a sheet in excel without it prompting you?  I am doing this with Dispatch in win32com.client.

```
import time, os.path, os
from win32com.client import Dispatch

path1 = 'C:\\example.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:\\Todolist2.xlsx'

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

wb1= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path1)
wb2= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path2)

ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)
ws2 = xl.ActiveSheet

ws1.Copy(Before=wb2.Worksheets(1))

ws2 = xl.ActiveSheet
ws2.Delete()
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks pretty similar to VBA code. In VBA you'd temporarily disable the alerts with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`; you can try doing something similar.

Comment: just add `xl.DisplayAlerts = False` that should do the trick

Comment: @FloLie Thank You that definitely did the trick!